# What is this 45-star American flag?

Tags: united-states, flag

I was watching the news today and spotted a very strange flag behind this talking head. It appears to be a U.S. flag with 45 stars arranged mostly in a circular pattern, but it doesn't look like the [official 45 star flag from 1896.](http://www.usflag.org/history/the45starflag.html)

Is it some rare version of the 45 star flag? Is it a political statement? Unfortunately I didn't catch the name of the talking head nor did I think to take a picture of who it was. I was too interested in the flag.

Below is the picture I took:

[image: please identify this flag]

(I was unsure if this was the correct place to ask, but I didn't know where else it would be. If there is a better stack for it, please let me know.)

Comment: The talking head is Steve Schmidt. He's appeared in front of that flag (as a talking head) a number of times on MSNBC

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Via Google reverse image search, I was able to uncover it is a rare old American flag with 45 stars in a medallion configuration made after Utah was admitted to the union.

Google results are sparse, but I found a little information at this link [at this link](https://jamesdjulia.com/item/2086-398/):

> **RARE 45-STAR MEDALLION FLAG COMMEMORATING THE STATE OF UTAH, 1896.**
>   Printed on cotton and framed. Canton shows triple circular wreaths of dancing stars surrounding a single star with additional stars in each quadrant. This flag was official from 1896-1908 and like other medallion patterns of this era is rare.

Comment: Seems factual, but any clue about why they aren't interested in AK, HI, AZ, NM, or OK? Or who the man is?

Comment: Wow! Good find! I'm sorry I don't have more information on the man, but if he was some representative from Utah it would make sense for him to have it in his office. Thanks!

Comment: [Here's another page](http://jeffbridgman.com/inventory/index.php?page=out&id=1225) with more (but not much) info about this type of flag.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt: ["I'll be deep in the cold, cold ground before I recognize Missourah"](https://frinkiac.com/caption/S06E09/1089137)

Comment: More background on the flag here: http://www.jeffbridgman.com/inventory/index.php?page=out&id=2913